# Looking for a Jekyll generator to create blog pages from the rows of a csv file in _data folder

Tags: ruby, csv, jekyll, generator, data-files

The title says it all.

The 'why would you want to do that" is simple. My team all edit a shared csv file and I use it as input for my dashboard. It's crude but it works and more importantly it respects the way people work. Nobody has to learn new software etc.

I currently display the data I need on static pages but increasingly, I'm thinking the dataset I'm using would map really nicely to to a blog structure.

Thanks:-)

Comment: A Content Management System CMS it not so hard to install and configure. This will be less error prone that manipulating a CSV file with nearly no constrains. See https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=static%20site%20generator%20cms

Comment: I have a CMS thanks. In this instance I'm using Jekyll on another project and I'm very happy with it. My problem is that I'm not a Ruby programmer and the docs for generators are very limited.